# How do I copy a the OS X DVD that came with my Mac using a Windows machine?

Tags: windows, dvd, osx-mountain-lion, iso-image, dvd-burning

Even with a clean install of Mountain Lion on an internal SSD, 8 GB of RAM, saving the ISO image to the internal SSD and two different brands (Verbatim & Titan) of unused dual layer DVD+R discs, Disk Utility will not burn the image without encountering errors (4 attempts failed).

Of course, there shouldn't be a problem and it may be the DVD drive but until that's fixed, I just want to create copies of the DVDs that came with my Mac.

Is there a way to use a Windows machine to copy and burn a dual layer DVD for use in a Mac?

Comment: You can try [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com) and create an ISO or BIN+CUE image, but I'm not sure whether it will copy the entire disc or just the Windows portion.

Answer (score 1):

[ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) will work fine.

At least it has for me in the past, for this very same thing.